# How to capture click event on Save button of CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, ckeditor

i try to capture the the click event occur on save button of CKEditor this way

```
  var element = CKEDITOR.document.getById('CKEditor1');
  element.on('click', function (ev) {
      //ev.removeListener();
      alert('hello');
      return false;
  });
```

but it is not working.when i click on save button of CKEditor then a postback occur. if possible help me with right code sample to capture click event occur on Save button of CKEditor. thanks

### I got the solution

```
  CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['save'] = {
      init: function (editor) {
         var command = editor.addCommand('save',
         {
              modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 },
              exec: function (editor) { // Add here custom function for the save button
              alert('You clicked the save button in CKEditor toolbar!');
              }
         });
         editor.ui.addButton('Save', { label: 'Save', command: 'save' });
      }
  }
```

the above code i was looking for. the above code help me to capture the click event of save button in toolbar. thanks

Comment: You tried with `ev.preventdefault();` to block postback?

Comment: Add `toolbar: 'document'` to the list of properties (e.g. after `command: 'save'`) in order to keep the save button with its group. Otherwise it ends up at the bottom right. Otherwise, works like a charm, thanks.

Comment: Actually this solution works best - if there are multiple editors on one page, this solution seems to be the only one that allows for easy separation of the incoming data for AJAX or whatever.

Comment: Please separate your answer from the question.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a (in my opinion) better/cleaner way to accomplish what you already figured out. This does nothing but replace the javascript that the save button runs, meaning it will not move the save button out of its original toolbar group:

html:

```
<textarea id="CKEditor1"></textarea>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    // Need to wait for the ckeditor instance to finish initialization
    // because CKEDITOR.instances.editor.commands is an empty object
    // if you try to use it immediately after CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {

        // Create a new command with the desired exec function
        var overridecmd = new CKEDITOR.command(editor, {
            exec: function(editor){
                // Replace this with your desired save button code
                alert(editor.document.getBody().getHtml());
            }
        });

        // Replace the old save's exec function with the new one
        ev.editor.commands.save.exec = overridecmd.exec;
    });

    CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditor1');

</script>
```

Comment: @liuyanghejerry What should be `ev.editor`? The variable `ev` only exists inside the anonymous function, where it is used (`ev.editor.commands.save.exec = overridecmd.exec;`). Outside of the function that variable does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

with `preventDefault()` If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.
Try this code please:

```
$(document).on('click', '#CKEditor1', function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   alert('hello');
   return false;
});
```

[This](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html) might help you.

Comment: this code is not working. when i click on save button then postback occur.what should i do.

Comment: @Thomas Check your ID, this code should _at least_ alert "hello" when it's being clicked. _Edit_: Also make sure this scrips is ran after the DOM is ready.

Comment: CKEditor1 has toolbar and in that toolbar there is a button for save. it has no relation with textarea. all people attach click event with textarea. so when we click on toolbar save button then actual click is not capture. so just guide me how to capture click event on the save button in the toolbar of ckeditor. any idea?

Comment: @Thomas [This](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html) might help you.

Comment: i got the solution and also update my question with right solution. just have a look. any way thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) documentation

```
Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.
```

add this  ...

```
 ev.preventDefault();
```

in you code

```
  $('#CKEditor1').on('click', function (ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      alert('hello');
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: this code is not working. when i click on save button then postback occur.what should i do.

Comment: CKEditor1 has toolbar and in that toolbar there is a button for save. it has no relation with textarea. all people attach click event with textarea. so when we click on toolbar save button then actual click is not capture. so just guide me how to capture click event on the save button in the toolbar of ckeditor. any idea?

Comment: i got the solution and also update my question with right solution. just have a look. any way thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mousedown` rather than `click` on submit button, and add `ev.preventDefault` to stop submit.

```
var element = CKEDITOR.document.getById('CKEditor1');
element.on('mousedown', function (ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   alert('hello');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: `$(elm).mousedown(...)` indirectly calls `$(elm).on('mousedown', ...)`, so there should be no difference.

Comment: CKEditor1 has toolbar and in that toolbar there is a button for save. it has no relation with textarea. all people attach click event with textarea. so when we click on toolbar save button then actual click is not capture. so just guide me how to capture click event on the save button in the toolbar of ckeditor. any idea?

Comment: @Thomas You should add this to your question to clarify.

Comment: i got the solution and also update my question with right solution. just have a look. any way thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ckeditorcontrol properties and find the prerender event so you can save your text in database with prerender event.

```
protected void CKEditorControl2_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CKEditorControl2.Text))
  {
    // write here what you want to save in your database.
  }
}
```